# making a function with a for loop to compare degrees of polynomial in polynomial regression

Tags: r, function, loops, polynomials

I want to make this code into a function with a for loop so that I can plug a variable into the function (where "age" is in this code) and get an ANOVA table out that compares the fit of each polynomial. I would like the fits examined to go up to fit_10.

```
fit_1 = lm(wage~age, data = Wage)
fit_2 = lm(wage~poly(age,2), data = Wage)
fit_3 = lm(wage~poly(age,3), data = Wage)
fit_4 = lm(wage~poly(age,4), data = Wage)
fit_5 = lm(wage~poly(age,5), data = Wage)
print(anova(fit_1,fit_2,fit_3,fit_4,fit_5))
```

Any help appreciated on this basic question!

Comment: For a more better behaved model, consider `mgcv::gam(wage ~ s(age), data = Wage)`!

Answer (score 2):

You may use `update.formula` in an `lapply`. To update the formula, we loop over `1:5` for desired polynomials and `paste/sprintf` a formula together in each iteration.

```
res <- lapply(1:5, \(x) lm(update(mpg ~ 1, paste('. ~', sprintf('poly(hp, %s)', x))), mtcars))
```

(Note, that if we just do `lapply(1:5, \(x) lm(mpg ~ poly(hp, x), mtcars))`, only the `poly(hp, x)` is stored in the call and not e.g. `poly(hp, 2)`.)

Then we `do.call` `anova` with the `res`-list as argument.

```
do.call('anova', res)
# Analysis of Variance Table
# 
# Model 1: mpg ~ poly(hp, 1)
# Model 2: mpg ~ poly(hp, 2)
# Model 3: mpg ~ poly(hp, 3)
# Model 4: mpg ~ poly(hp, 4)
# Model 5: mpg ~ poly(hp, 5)
#   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq       F    Pr(>F)    
# 1     30 447.67                                   
# 2     29 274.63  1   173.043 16.8050 0.0003606 ***
# 3     28 269.61  1     5.026  0.4881 0.4909752    
# 4     27 269.52  1     0.087  0.0085 0.9272928    
# 5     26 267.72  1     1.794  0.1742 0.6798122    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```